# Google cast sender app showing SAMPLE watermark on tv screen when connected

Tags: android, chromecast, live-streaming, exoplayer, google-cast-sdk

I am developing an Android app within which I am trying to setup the Google cast framework and trying to play remote live streams on a chromecast device from my app.

Now, when the devices are connected and when I try to cast on my TV screen with RemoteMediaPlayer from CAF as described here - https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/android_sender/integrate

it does cast the media on to my TV but it has a big huge watermark on screen written as SAMPLE.

Can anybody please suggest as to how to remove this sample written all over my casted screen ? and why am I even seeing this watermark in the first place? is this because the app is in development mode or using an invalid receiver app id or something ?

Please let me know if I can provide any more info that can help identify / fix the issue.

Comment: Are you using google's videos provided in the sample ? Because in that case it will show SAMPLE

Comment: No, we are using our own live streams to test

Answer (score 1):

You have to change your app_id to **CC1AD845**.

[Source](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/cast/CastMediaControlIntent.html#DEFAULT_MEDIA_RECEIVER_APPLICATION_ID)

Using this id should remove **SAMPLE** watermark

Since this constant might change you can also use `CastMediaControlIntent.DEFAULT_MEDIA_RECEIVER_APPLICATION_ID`